# MVVM Silverlight DataGrid : Binding Columns Collection

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I need to access data grid's columns collection in my model class but when i try this it says that the data grid's columns property doesn't has an accessible setter.

So are there any workarounds for accessing Columns property in model class?

My XAML code is like this :

```
<sdk:DataGrid RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"  Columns="{Binding GridColumns, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" 
                      ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,27" HeadersVisibility="Column" Grid.Row="1"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataList, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`t bind to `Columns` property because it`s not `DependencyProperty`. So just add columns from code if you need to pass them from somewhere else. If they are not context dependent then assigning them in XAML would probably be better.

On a side note, "*access data grid's columns collection in my model*" sounds rather strange for MVVM. Normally model shouldn`t even know what`s a `DataGrid`.

Comment: By adding columns from code, do you mean code behind? If so, our supervisors don't want any coding in code behind. All process must be done in model class. I found a way for bind grid itself to a datagrid object in model class. Thanks anyway.